# Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Здравствуйте. Решил обновить студию, удалил 13 версию поставил 15. В результате чего перестали работать базы данных созданные на 13 версии(12 версия sql сервера). Так и не получилось запустить их на 15 студии(14 версия sql сервера). Удалил 15 студию, зачистил всё что относится и к 12 и к 14 sql серверам. Поставил назад 13 студию. Пытаюсь открыть базу данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь установить скачанный с официального сайта ms sql localdb 12:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя когда проверяю версию с помощью запроса `select @@version`

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (Intel X86)   Oct 19 2012 13:43:21   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Но почему то выдаёт что у меня версия 11. (localdb)\v11.0
Хотя по моему это для 14 версии, а для 12 должно быть по моему (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB. Как раз последнее у меня в настройках вижуал студии для базы данных. В чём дело, что я делаю не так? Как можно снести полностью 14 версию sql сервера и снова нормально поставить 12 и запускать базы данных?
Подскажите пожалуйста, уже всю голову сломал.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не понятно, что Вы обновили - студию или сервер?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis когда ставишь 15 студию с ней автоматом ставиться 14 версия sql сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Local DB позволяет на лету создавать инстансы разных версий.

Имена инстансов к версиям не привязаны - т.е. (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB может быть любой версии, в зависимости от того, какая версия была указана при создании инстанса.

Список инстансов можно посмотреть утилитой

```
sqllocaldb i
```

Данные по конкретному инстансу

```
sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB
```

там же есть параметры для вывода доступных версий (`v`) и для удаления / создания инстансов. Если вас версия конкретного инстанса не устраивает - удалит его и создайте заново с указанием нужной версии.

Для первой ошибки - то же самое - вы пытаетесь подключится к инстансу, которого нет. Посмотрие имя инстанса из connection string и создайте его через `sqllocaldb c`

Comment: PashaPash, подсажите пожалуйста, где прописывать эти команды? В командной строке? Просто немного не разобрался как это делать. Подскажите пожалуйста поподробнее как создавать и дуалять инстансы, а то уже всю голову сломал

Comment: PashaPash, вроде немного разобрался, удалил инстенс Projects и инстенс v11.0, хотя он всё равно отображается если ввести `sqllocaldb i`, но если посмотреть конкретно по нему информацию то не находит нечего и удалять его уже нельзя, создал инстенс `MSSQLLocalDB` новые базы создаются, но вот старые не подцепляются, все скрины привожу в вопросе. ПОдскажите пожалуйста что я сделал не так.